# ValueError: Number of label does not match number of samples

Tags: python, csv, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I'm a rookie when it comes to data science. I have a dataset I am using but I decided to take it a step further by importing from a csv using numpy which it does. The problem is I am trying to do some prediction using the tree classifier but it is throwing up the error.

```
x = np.loadtxt('sample.csv',unpack = True,delimiter=",",
                 skiprows=1, usecols=[0,2])

y = np.loadtxt('sample.csv',unpack = True,delimiter=",",
                 skiprows=1, usecols=[3], dtype =str)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(x,y)

prediciton = clf.predict([[190,50,60]])
```

the csv is in a group of 4 columns. I am trying to use the values of the first 3 to predict the 4th.

Comment: This error indicates that you are trying to train the classifier on a dataset that consists of X samples and Y labels of those samples, where X =/= Y. Essentially, you gave some samples to your training function, but not every sample has a label, so it doesn't know what to do with it. Check what you are giving to `clf.fit()`.

Comment: found the problem but don't know how to solve it. The numpy turns my Y value to a sinle list of arrays instead of individual values

Comment: I have this [[ 181.  177.  160. ...,  159.  171.  181.]
 [  44.   43.   38. ...,   37.   42.   43.]]
["b'male'" "b'male'" "b'female'" ..., "b'female'" "b'male'" "b'male'"]   instead of this   [[181, 80, 44], [177, 70, 43], [160, 60, 38], [154, 54, 37], [166, 65, 40], [190, 90, 47], [175, 64, 39], [177, 70, 40], [159, 55, 37], [171, 75, 42], [181, 85, 43]]
['male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']
['male']

Comment: Try importing the csv using pandas I find it a little cleaner than numpy, it might fix your problem

Comment: already on it thanks